# Revoking admin consent for a Microsoft Chat Bot

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I have created a microsoft chat bot, and have set up the [/adminconsent workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service), where another application has given admin consent to my bot to act on behalf of them.

@shawn-tabrizi wrote a [great article about how to remove my own bot's access to their application from the UI](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/aad/revoking-consent-azure-active-directory-applications/), but I can't find a way to remove access using Microsoft Graph.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [Delete an appRoleAssignment granted to a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-delete-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http):

> App roles which are assigned to service principals are also known as application permissions. Deleting an app role assignment for a service principal is equivalent to revoking the app-only permission grant.